# Python Pandas read_csv function does not allow to change parsed dates into required format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, format

I am a python beginner and am trying to read a csv file with pandas. The issue is that the date column in the csv has following format: 2020-03-12 00:00:00+00:00. Within the read_csv function already, I want to change the date format into isoformat (%Y-%m-%d). I tried all stackoverflow solutions but none of them work. This is my code:

```
import time
from datetime import date

url = 'https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/items/f10774f1c63e40168479a1feb6c7ca74/data'
countries = pd.read_csv(url,
                     usecols=[2, 5, 8],
                     index_col=['Landkreis', 'Meldedatum'],
                     parse_dates=['Meldedatum'],
                     squeeze=True
                       ).sort_index()
```

[Current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sl0Ps.png)

The column "Meldedatum" should only show the date, not the hours and minutes. Yet, I can't change the format because it is an index column.

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: `2020-03-12 00:00:00+00:00` is just how `pandas` displays the datetime column (index). There's no point in changing the format.

Comment: note: check e.g. `countries.index[0]` and you see that your second index, from the `Meldedatum` column, is `Timestamp('2020-03-12 00:00:00+0000', tz='UTC')`. Since you called `read_csv` with `parse_dates=['Meldedatum']` and the `Meldedatum` column is correct ISO 8601 datetime strings, pandas does its job and everything is fine ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Read your csv normally into dataframe without specifying any format.

Then do this:

```
countries['Meldedatum'] = pd.to_datetime(countries['Meldedatum'])
```

This should give you the format you want.

Comment: I think the OP's code already correctly parses to datetime. It's just a matter of displaying things...

Comment: This code generates the same representation that OP started with.

Answer (score 0):

That's just how pandas displays a `datetime` object. It always stores fields for hours/minutes/seconds/miliseconds, even if they are all set to zero. You can't change this internal representation.

You can, however, cast `datetime` objects to string, in order to format their representation the way you want. Keep in mind that you lose all functionality of a `datetime` object along the way.

It looks like you want to count the number of occurrences per day. If that's the case, you should use a `groupby` object. We don't need to set the index columns or parse dates in this case. We can also convert the representation of the `datetime` objects to strings, if that's your preference:

```
import time
from datetime import date 

import pandas as pd 

# get the data
url = 'https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/items/f10774f1c63e40168479a1feb6c7ca74/data' 
countries = pd.read_csv(url, usecols=[2, 5, 8], index_col=None, squeeze=True).sort_index()
# modify dates to strings
countries['Meldedatum'] = countries.Meldedatum.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.split('T')[0])
# group by Landkreis and Meldedatum
grouped_countries = countries.groupby(['Landkreis', 'Meldedatum']).count()

print(grouped_countries)

# output:
                               AnzahlFall
Landkreis          Meldedatum                 
LK Ahrweiler       2020-03-12           5
                   2020-03-13           2
                   2020-03-14           1
                   2020-03-16           3
                   2020-03-17           5
...                                   ...
StadtRegion Aachen 2020-04-14           8
                   2020-04-15          37
                   2020-04-16          23
                   2020-04-17          18
                   2020-04-18           5
```